# How to set Identity Provider Entity ID of SAML Identity Provider in Keycloak with Terraform Keycloak Provider

Tags: terraform, keycloak

I'm trying to setup a SAML IDP in keycloak (version 21.1.1) via terraform with [keycloak_saml_identity_provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/edflex-tech/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/saml_identity_provider) Resource.

I cannot find a way to setup the Identity provider entity ID for issuer validation. I cannot fill this field in the UI:

[image: Identity provider entity ID field in keycloak IDP setup]

Does anyone know the param or extraConfig key for this?

Here is my setup so far:

```
resource "keycloak_saml_identity_provider" "google_saml" {
    realm        = keycloak_realm.realm.id
    alias        = "test_google_saml"
    display_name = "TEST"
  
    entity_id                  = var.google_SAML_SP_entity_id
    single_sign_on_service_url = var.google_SAML_IDP_SSO_service_url
  
    trust_email                = true
    sync_mode                  = "FORCE"
    name_id_policy_format      = "Email"
    principal_type             = "SUBJECT"
    post_binding_response      = true
    post_binding_authn_request = true
    store_token                = false
    force_authn                = false
    validate_signature         = false
    extra_config               = {
      "allowCreate" : true
      "identityProviderEntityID" : var.google_SAML_IDP_entity_id
    }
  }
```

Comment: First step would be to verify that it is exposed in the API endpoint. If it is, and you are certain it is not available in the resource, then next step is a feature request with the provider, or PR it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close! The extra_config parameter is `idpEntityId` rather than `identityProviderEntityID`.

The easiest way to see the possible extra options is to open your identity provider's settings in the Keycloak GUI with the Network tab of your browser's developer tools open. There will be a GET request to`/admin/realms/glean/identity-provider/instances/your-idps-alias` and the response to this request will list the full config of the IdP.

Comment: Thank you so much - especially for the hint how to find out the param id. Works fine